# QUiLoader and ignored dynamic properties

Tags: qt

I'm loading the .ui file, where one of the widgets (QComboBox) has a dynamic property (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/properties.html#dynamic-properties). The UI file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
<class>PopulateScriptConfig</class>
<widget class="QWidget" name="PopulateScriptConfig">
  <property name="geometry">
  <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
  </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
  <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
  <item>
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="langGroup">
    <property name="title">
      <string>Language</string>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
      <item>
      <widget class="QComboBox" name="langCombo">
        <property name="ScriptingLangCombo" stdset="0">
        <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
      </widget>
      </item>
    </layout>
    </widget>
  </item>
  <item>
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="codeGroup">
    <property name="title">
      <string>Implementation</string>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
      <item>
      <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="codeEdit"/>
      </item>
    </layout>
    </widget>
  </item>
  </layout>
</widget>
<resources/>
<connections/>
</ui>
```

The important part is:

```
      <widget class="QComboBox" name="langCombo">
        <property name="ScriptingLangCombo" stdset="0">
        <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
      </widget>
```

I'm loading the file with `QUiLoader::load()`. I have extended the `QUiLoader` class, but only to access `createWidget()` method, where I can query each widget like this:

```
QWidget* UiLoader::createWidget(const QString& className, QWidget* parent, const QString& name)
{
    QWidget* w = QUiLoader::createWidget(className, parent, name);
    qDebug() << w->dynamicPropertyNames();
    return w;
}
```

As a result I see empty list displayed, so it seems like the dynamic property is completly ignored.

Note, that UI editor in QtCreator recognizes this dynamic property correclty.

This question was already asked/reported 2 times before, but no solution was provided:

1. [https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-11791?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-11791?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3aactivity-stream-issue-tab)
2. http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32013-QUiLoader-Problem-No-Dynamic-Properties-Support

Any ideas?

P.S. I've made sure that I load correct file. 3 times.

Comment: I did test this on the most simple example project and I confirm this is not related to anything I've done (reimplementing createWidget() or anything else). This is a bug in QUiLoader. Dynamic properties work correctly when forms are generated into C++ code from UI files at build time, but not when loaded with QUiLoader.

Comment: For now I've implemented a huge (and not very nice) workaround, which lets my application load the UI file independently from `QUiLoader` and it parses it with `QXmlSimpleReader` to make a list of dynamic properties for all widgets inside. Then, in overriden version of QUiLoader::createWidget() I apply all those dynamic properties to the widget basing on widgets name. Unfortunately I won't paste the entire solution here, cause it's huge. Despite my workaround, the original question remains. Maybe there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was my mistake and Qt is working correctly. Rookie mistake.

1. The problem is that I tried to access dynamic properties in overriden method of `QUiLoader::createWidget()`, but this is invoked for each subwidget and dynamic properties are set after all widgets were created. Dynamic properties are not yet available at the moment of `createWidget()` call.
2. The very simple project I did for testing this (I mentioned it in the comment) was also working correctly, I just made a mistake while printing debug information (I was printing it from wrong widget). That's all.

QUiLoader works just fine with dynamic properties after all.